DB stuck on synchronized/recovery pending + ALT DB SET ONLINE
Im curious to understand this scenario if there was a better plan.
Index maintenance caused the log to grow, filling the disk and causing a db to go into SYNCHRONIZED/RECOVERY PENDING.
we ran ALTER DATABASE SET ONLINE and we are now waiting looking at HADR_SYNC_COMMIT on Sp_whoisactive.
would be a better idea removing the db from aoag first and then set online + that way the db would be online fast and later we would be able to add to aoag without impact much the customers.
I'm worried how much time this will take to sync back, because it even has that famous black background task locked by the HADR_SYNC_COMMIT ,that's locking everything else.
